# Transparent Box with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, transparent

I want to make a transparent box with content inside it with the image below..

[image: example image]

I have no idea about creating this. Should I use HTML5 techniques?
Would you please give me some help about creating this box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rgba()` values for `background-color` and control the opacity by changing the alpha value(`rgba(r, g, b, a)`).

```css
div {
  background: rgba(100, 10, 10, 0.7);
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body, html {
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400) 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: was about to do the same thing +1 http://jsfiddle.net/pzzezzjr/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yb69nw1u/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
<div class="box-transparent">
    This is some demo Text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-transparent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

The important thing is the `rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);` line.
0.6 is the box's opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just uses a background image:

HTML

```
<div class="box">
   text text text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: url("http://www.placecage.com/400/200");
}
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqw87sng/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use opacity property

```
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

or you can make only background transparent with rgba background color:

```
div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: if you are using opacity the content inside will also get the opacity you will need to use 2 different elements or pseudo element

Comment: this is why I include 'only background opacity' option in my answer. I know that this do not include transparent image bg, but I am lazy googling and did't memorize all css possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba as a background color.

background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5) 
will give the background the color rgb(30,30,30) and an opacity of 0.5.

Just play a bit with the last value.